# Eslint --fix supresses errors but doesn't actually change file

Tags: gulp, eslint

I'm using gulp and eslint to build my code, and when I ran lint I had a ton of indentation / spacing errors. I added the fix flag to my gulpfile:

```js
gulp.task('lint', function() {
    return gulp
        .src([config.tap.src])
        .pipe(eslint({
            fix:true,
            envs: ['jquery', 'browser']
          }
        ))
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
});
```

and the errors were gone. However, my files seem  to have the same incorrect indentations as before; according to the docs fix should change my files right? Is there another parameter I need to fix these changes?

For example I got the error:

```
12:1   error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 12
```

but after fixing the indentation is still the same.
Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: How are you viewing these files?

Comment: An IDE called Atom. But also these changes are not showing up in a Github pull request -- afaik git always shows indentation / spacing changes

Comment: Chances are the `--fix` flag does it's job correctly, and Atom was just beautifying the view of the problematic files. Try viewing them before and after applying the fix with a "simple" text editor like Notepad or vi.

Comment: I thought this was the case until I saw no changes on my git PR. 
I just tested using notepad though -- it doesn't fix the indentation, even though there are no errors or warnings. I checked out master branch (which has no fix), ran `gulp lint`, got an error for a line with 4 spaces instead of 2. Switched to the `fix:true` branch, ran `gulp lint`, no errors, still 4 spaces

Answer (score 4):

So as it turns out, with eslint, you need to specify where the fix is saved to. Other SO threads suggested `gulp.dest('.')` or `gulp.dest('./')` but these created new folders for me, instead of overwriting the originals. What I posted below worked for me.

```js
return gulp
  .src([config.src])
  .pipe(eslint({ fix: true }))
  .pipe(eslint.format())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(file => file.base))
  .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
```